# Ionic 4 how to disable swipe or scroll content for ios

Tags: ios, ionic4

I need to disable specific for ios swipe or scroll (i don't know how it named correctly).
When we scroll content down (no more data), and after it we can scroll content again (Only in ios).
Can i disable it?

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqw-pZDTw_8)

Comment: Hey! Just so I'm understanding, it looks like there should be more TableView data listed (or however you're pulling the data)? I watched the video and it shows someone's name I believe, but no data in the way that's listed above.

Comment: Also, in regards to disabling it: It seems like your scroll view is taller than your iPhone, so naturally it has to scroll. Unless I'm misunderstanding, it sounds like you'll have to shorter to view controller itself.

Answer (score 0):

Dmitriy Ler , scrolling behaviour on iOS devices has extend scrolling even there is no items below/above the list's.
Same issue i was facing with my project , It took almost 3 weeks to find root cause.

Then i published my solution to `npm`

Please reach out to this library , It'll definitely solves your problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/disable-ios-scrolling